# When I am sending an email it should go in selected preferred language ,I am passing dynamic data in object but i am unable to translate it in .ts

Tags: html, css, json, angular, typescript

```
 let inviteUSer = {
        emailId: recipient_name,
        community_id: this.communityID,
        created_by: this.userid,
        batch_id: this.batchId,
        //userName:recipient_name,
        batch_name: this.batch_name,
        encodedLink: this.encodelink1,
        community_name: this.model.comm_name
      }
      console.log(inviteUSer);
      this._batchitem.getInviteUser(inviteUSer).subscribe(res => {
        if (res.success == true) {
          recipient_name='';
          console.log(res, "ths is invited user");
        } else {
         
          if(res.status=='400'){    
                
            $('#exampleModal').modal('show');   
            
          } 
          else{ 
            console.log(res,'error for invite ');   
          }
        }
      });
```

I am using Angular 5 .The value which I am passing in object that should go in converted language form. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to send it in formdata ?

Comment: no @FaizalHussain

Comment: I am trying to send object data in language specific , whenever I select specific language from drop down list , my data should go in converted language